# The typescript build is uselessly verbose

Tags: typescript

I want undestand why typescript produce a verbose output with some (maybe) uselessly lines of code.

I have this method in a typescript file `helloWorld.ts`:

```
export const helloWorld = () => alert("Hello World!");
```

after the build it become `helloWorld.js` with this code:

```
"use strict";
Object.defineProperty(exports, "__esModule", { value: true });
exports.helloWorld = void 0;
const helloWorld = () => alert("Hello World!");
exports.helloWorld = helloWorld;
```

There are some parts that seem unnecessary

Why typescript define a `helloWorld` porperty into `exports` with `undefined` (`void 0`)

```
exports.helloWorld = void 0;
```

instead of directly:

```
exports.helloWorld = () => alert("Hello World!");
```

in this way the code is more minimized and doing the same thing:

```
"use strict";
Object.defineProperty(exports, "__esModule", { value: true });
exports.helloWorld = () => alert("Hello World!");
```

my tsconfig.json

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "incremental": false,
    "target": "es2019",
    "outDir": "build",
    "rootDir": "src",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "declaration": true,
    "inlineSourceMap": false,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "removeComments": false,
    "strict": true,
    "strictNullChecks": true,
    "noUnusedLocals": true,
    "noUnusedParameters": true,
    "noImplicitReturns": true,
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,
    "traceResolution": false,
    "listEmittedFiles": false,
    "listFiles": false,
    "pretty": true,
    "lib": [
      "es2019",
      "dom"
    ],
    "types": [
      "node"
    ],
    "typeRoots": [
      "node_modules/@types",
      "src/types"
    ]
  },
  "include": [
    "src/**/*.ts"
  ],
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules/**"
  ],
  "compileOnSave": false
}
```

Comment: Your title and your body seem to be asking two different question: minifying is not a job that the TS compiler should do, that can be done as an additional step. But whether or not some code lines are necessary at all is a different question. Which one do you really care about?

Comment: the JS `target` in `tsconfig.json` determines what version typescript compiles "down" to. The lower the `es` version, the more verbose the javascript will become.

Comment: @GenerousBadger I have update the question with more focus on "how typescript works and why"

Comment: @ar099968 you compile to `commonjs` with `esModuleInterop` that's why.

Comment: If you compile to `esnext` it'll do nothing at all